# Snowflake Stage Error "OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device "

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I'm working on Snowflake Stored Procedure, trying to store trained ML model and other related artifacts like encoder and columns to be encoded in training pipeline to snowflake Stage. But I Keep getting this error "OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device "  everytime I try to store, even though in stage I can see space of 250MB available for each file and model I'm using is Random Forest ( which is less than 100 MB ).

```
Sample Code

encoder_filename = model_type + "encoder.joblib"
encoder_model_file = os.path.join(''/tmp'', encoder_filename)
joblib.dump(encoder, encoder_model_file)
session.file.put(encoder_model_file, "@DB.Schema",overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Looks like, Issue is with the /tmp folder storage, which size warehouse you are using. Try using bigger size warehouse as it will have more ssd and ram

Comment: Hi - 1) How/where are you running this code 2) how are you determining the space available in the stage? Given that the storage on Snowflake is effectively unlimited, it seems likely that this error related to the environment where you are running these commands, not to Snowflake

Comment: @ADITYAPAWAR yes.. this was the issue , Thanks

Comment: @NickW 1. running in python stored proc 2. in stage when we upload a new file there was a max limit.